# Header files for linux 3.10.25

Tags: linux, debian, vmware, headers

I just tried to install VMware player, but it asks for header files.
I compiled them with *make-kpkg* command, and recieved a .deb package.
When I try to install it, console says:

"Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.10.25 cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.10.25 package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located"

But when I try 'dkms' it says:

```
dkms: command not found
```

How can I solve it?

My `/etc/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.3.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20131215-04:55]/ wheezy main 
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.3.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20131215- 04:55]/ wheezy main 
deb http://mirror.mephi.ru/debian/ wheezy main 
deb http://mirror.mephi.ru/debian/ wheezy main 
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main 
# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile' 
deb http://mirror.mephi.ru/debian/ wheezy-updates main 
deb-src http://mirror.mephi.ru/debian/ wheezy-updates main 
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main import backport upstream romeo
```

Comment: Which Debian are you using? The kernel headers for 3.10 are in the repositories, if you can't find them, please post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the linux headers. It is most convenient to install **one** of these three packages:

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-486                       
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-686-pae                  
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-amd64
```

Which one is suitable to your machine is not specified in your OP, you may try them until you find the one for which there are no error messages. You can, however, get an idea from the output of this command, which in my case  is:

```
 > uname -a
 Linux dPor 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.53-2 i686 GNU/Linux
```

The architecture of my system is obviously 686-pae, which requires *linux-headers-686-pae*. Likewise for you.

And, just to make extra sure, after this issue the command

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

which will load other packages absolutely necessary to compile source files.

Comment: I have
`Linux debian 3.10.25-std400-amd64` kernel
but in repositories there are headers for 3.2.0.4 verision

Comment: @RealCake Where did you download this kernel from? Wherever you downloaded it from, you will find also the headers package.

Comment: I have downloaded tarball from kernel.org`s ftp

Comment: According to man page, make-kpkd can make package with headers from kernel source

Comment: @realCake Then the command sudo make-kpg kernel_headers produces the headers; after that sudo dpkg -i nameofpackage.deb installs it.

Comment: When I try to install package it gives an error
`Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.10.25 cannot be found. Please install the linux-headers-3.10.25 package, or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located`

Comment: @RealCake Try the same commands as before using fakeroot instead of sudo (you may have to apt-get install fakeroot), so. fakeroot kernel_headers; and now sudo dpkg -i nameofpackage.deb.

Comment: root@debian:/usr/src# fakeroot kernel_headers  
fakeroot: FAKEROOTKEY set to 593975958  
fakeroot: nested operation not yet supported

Comment: @RealCake The command kakeroot must be issued as a regular user; also, (my mistake), I meant fakeroot make-kpkg kernel_headers

Comment: I have tried that, the same error actually

Comment: @RealCake Move to Debian sid/testing, install kernel from repos, including headers.

Comment: Maybe I am stupid, but it seems that there are no linux-headers-3.10.25

Comment: @RealCake There are,they should be produced by the command above. You are probably issuing the command in the wrong dir.

Comment: I am seaching on packages.debian.org in every section.